# Behavior of read function when child receive a sigstop signal

Tags: c, unix, process, fork, system

## Explanation of the program

The programs spawns n child process that are paused right after being created. After that, those child processes take turn to talk to the parent process via pipes.

They talk for a fixed amount of time (ex: should talk for a total of 20 times but stop when they've talked 7 times consecutively and pass to the next process)

### Flow of the program

1. Forking all the childs
2. Pausing them right after their creation
3. Waking them up by sending a signal
4. Child write (for a fixed amount of time) to parent via pipe and then stop itself right after sending a signal to parent / Parent read content of pipe and write to STDOUT
5. When parent receive signal change pipe to read other child and signal wake up the following child

### The problem

The problem i'm facing is that when it is time to transition to the next process in order to listen to it, I don't get anything from the pipe of the following child even though I do write on the write-end of the pipe in the child process. Is there something I'm missing about SIGSTOP and SIGCONT when reading.

NB: I did read the docs

### Program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <signal.h>

#define LOOP_SIZE 20;

/* SIG HANDLERS DEFINITION */
void parentsighandler(int);

/* GLOBAL VARIABLE DEFINITION */ 
pid_t n, ppid, wpid;
int nb_args,  read_return;

// array of pid_t to send signals to child
pid_t  *child_pids;     

volatile sig_atomic_t status = 0;
volatile sig_atomic_t compteur = 0;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){   
    write(STDERR_FILENO, "** Begining the program\n", 24); // debug
    nb_args = argc - 1; 
    if (nb_args >= 1 ){
        // Variable initialisation
        child_pids= malloc(nb_args * sizeof(pid_t)); 

        // String for sprintf
        char sstr[40]; 
        char rstr[40];
        char pidstr[23];
        char strichild[16];
        char strloopchild[10];

        // Initializing all the pipes for the processes
        int p[2 * nb_args];  

        // getting the pid of the parent process
        ppid = getpid();
        sprintf(pidstr, "Pid of parent is : %d\n", ppid);
        write(STDERR_FILENO, pidstr, 23); // debug

        int i, j, stop_val;

        //Initializing all pipes
        write(STDERR_FILENO, "**Init pipes\n", 13); // debug
        for (i = 0; i < nb_args; i++){
            if (pipe(&p[2*i]) == -1){
                perror("Error : pipe failed");
                _exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
        }
        write(STDERR_FILENO, "**end init pipes\n", 17); // debug
        write(STDERR_FILENO, "**Begin fork\n", 15); // debug 
        for (i = 0; i <  nb_args; i ++){
            switch( n = fork()){
            case -1:
                perror("Error : fork failed");
                _exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            case 0:
                /* CHILD */
                sprintf(strichild, "**In child n%d\n", i); // debug
                write(STDERR_FILENO, strichild, strlen(strichild)); // debug
                if (0 == (stop_val = atoi(argv[i+1]))){
                    perror("atoi failed");
                    _exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                }
                sprintf(strichild, "stop_val is : %d\n", stop_val); // debug
                write(STDERR_FILENO, strichild, strlen(strichild)); // debug
                close(p[i*2]);
                for (j = 1; j <= 20 ; j++){
                    sprintf(strloopchild, "loop : %d\n", j); // debug
                    write(STDERR_FILENO, strloopchild , strlen(strloopchild)); // debug
                    if (j % stop_val == 0){
                        write(STDERR_FILENO, "I am  paused\n", 15); // debug
                        if ( kill(ppid, SIGUSR1) == -1){
                            write(STDERR_FILENO, "Could not kill\n",15); // debug
                        }
                        write(STDERR_FILENO, "Sent a sigusr1\n",15); // debug
                        kill(getpid(), SIGSTOP);

                    } 
                    write(STDERR_FILENO, "In child : ",11);  
                    sprintf(sstr, "J ecris sur l'entree %d du pipe\n", i*2+1);  
                    write(STDERR_FILENO, sstr, strlen(sstr));
                    sprintf(sstr, "Je suis le proc %d : message %d\n", getpid(), j);
                    write(STDERR_FILENO, sstr, 40); // debug
                    write(p[i * 2 + 1], sstr, 40);
                    sleep(1);

                }   
                close(p[i*2+1]);
                write(STDERR_FILENO, "**Exiting the child\n", 20); // debug
                _exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);

            default:
                /* PARENT - process scheduling */
                write(STDERR_FILENO, "**Parent - puting to sleep childs\n", 34); // debug 
                child_pids[i] = n;
                kill(n, SIGSTOP);
                // Setting up the signal
                signal(SIGUSR1, parentsighandler); 
            } 
        }
        write(STDOUT_FILENO, "Debut de l'ordonnancement\n",26);
        char strpids[20];
        for (i = 0; i < nb_args; i++){
            sprintf(strpids, "id processus : %d\n", child_pids[i]);
            write(STDOUT_FILENO, strpids, 20);
        }
        char mystr[17];
        sprintf(mystr, "compteur : %d\n", compteur); // debug
        write(STDOUT_FILENO, mystr, 17); // debug  
        kill(child_pids[compteur], SIGCONT);
        while(1){
            if (read(p[2 * compteur], rstr, 40) > 0) {
                write(STDOUT_FILENO,"P : ",5);
                write(STDOUT_FILENO, rstr, 40);
                sprintf(mystr, "compt value: %d\n", compteur); // debug
                write(STDOUT_FILENO, mystr, 17); // debug 
            } else {
                write(STDERR_FILENO, "Erreur lecture\n", 15);
            } 
            sleep(1);
        }


    } else {
        perror("Error : Not enough args\n");
        _exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }   
    return 0;
}

void parentsighandler(int sig){
    if (sig == SIGUSR1){
        write(STDOUT_FILENO, "*************\n", 14);//debug
        write(STDOUT_FILENO, "P : going into sig handler\n", 28); // debug
        if (compteur == (nb_args - 1)){
            compteur = 0;   
        } else {
            compteur ++;
        }
        kill(child_pids[compteur], SIGCONT);

        char strst[19];
        sprintf(strst, "P : compteur : %d\n", compteur); // debug
        write(STDOUT_FILENO, strst, 19); // debug 
        write(STDOUT_FILENO, "*************\n", 14);//debug
    }
}
```

Comment: Every child has access to all the pipes, but closes only one.  Is that intentional?  Is every child supposed to be able to write to the pipe of all the other children?

Comment: I'm supposed to close every other one ?

Comment: If you don't close them in the other children, you won't read EOF from the pipe until all children exit.

Comment: Instead of `pipe[2*nb_args]`, use `pipe[nb_args][2]`, then you don't have to keep multiplying by 2 everywhere.

Comment: You're making lots of assumptions about the order that all the child processes will run. Also, signals aren't queued. If multiple children send SIGUSR1 before the parent's handler runs, it will only see one of them.

Comment: How should I structure the code in order to avoid signals problem. I want the child to send messages to the parent and the parent to write to STDOUT and repeat the process. Does read only stop when we have EOF

Comment: The *parent* should close its copies of the write ends of the pipes, too, since it's the children that write.  And if it does so, then just a little bit of care will ensure that the children don't need to worry about that.

Comment: `read()` does not normally wait for EOF unless there are no data at all available to return.  But it also does not necessarily recapitulate the writer's writes on a 1:1 basis.  Data from multiple `write()`s may be read by the same `read()`, and under some circumstances, data from one `write()` may be spread across multiple `read()`s.

Comment: If you're programming for POSIX, which seems likely, since `fork()` is not in the C standard, then you ought to use `sigaction()`, not `signal()`, to install signal handler functions.  And you should need only to do it once, not every time you fork a child.

Comment: regarding: `sprintf(strpids, "id processus : %d\n", child_pids[i]);`  this is assuming that the number of child_pids will never by greater than 2 digits.  Is that what you want?

Comment: this statement: `sprintf(strichild, "stop_val is : %d\n", stop_val);` causes the compiler to output: "note: ‘sprintf’ output between 17 and 27 bytes into a destination of size 16" which results in undefined behavior

Comment: OT: the posted code contains several 'magic' numbers  I.E. 5, 10, 11, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 23, 26, 27, 34, 40  Most of which can be replaced with `sizeof()` operators,  Suggest using `#define` statements or a `enum` statement to give those 'magic' numbers meaningful names, then use those meaningful names throughout the code

Comment: @user3629249 Could you give me an example on how you would use sizeof(). Can I use a char buffer with a greater capacity that write is going to fill ?

Comment: here is a way to eliminate one of the 'magic' numbers:  `write(STDERR_FILENO, pidstr, 23);`  can be changed to `write( STDERR_FILENO, pidstr, strlen( pidstr ) );`  most of the other 'magic' numbers can be eliminated in a similar manner